# Differential Manifold Embedding into Euclidean Space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to understand a proof in the subject of differential manifolds.
In the book im reading, there is a theorem that states:
"Let $M$ be a differential manifold with a local finite atlas, then there exist $N \in \Bbb N$ and an $embedding$ of M into $\Bbb R^N$ "

the proof structure goes as follows:

1. First they defining a map smooth map $F:M \to \Bbb R^N$. Showing this map  $F$ is injective, and that $F^{-1}:F(M) \to M$ has a local smooth extension,  which means that $F$ is homeomorphic to its image $F(M)$.
2. Secondly, showing the differential $dF_p:T_pM \to T_{F(p)}\Bbb R^N$ is injective for every p, so F is immersive.
3. showing that $F(M)$ is an m-dim manifold in $\Bbb R^N$
4. Concluding that $F$ is a diffeomorphism $M \to F(M)$.

Now, my question-

From what I learned, an embedding $f:M \to N$, means that $f(M)$ can be given with the structure of embedded submanifold of N (i.e f(M) is submanifold, which have the induced topology of N, such that the inclusion $i:f(M) \to N$ is smooth and immersion.)

So, How the proof provided above telling anything about the inclusion $i:F(M) \to \Bbb R^N$? And how can I conclude this inclusion is immersive at any p?
And also, why do I need $F$ to be diffeomorphism in order to show its an embedding?

thanks a lot!